# S3 upload fails due to import modules collision

Tags: python, boto3, grequests

I am using a python script to upload a file to s3 bucket. However I was facing an error like

```
S3 Upload Failed with exception : An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: cannot switch to a different thread
```

when I investigated, I found strange behavior of packages `boto3` and `grequests`

when I import `grequests` and `boto3` in my script it throws an exception. but same when I remove `import grequests` from my code the file gets uploaded to s3 with no issues.

```
import sys, os, time
import grequests
import boto3, ntpath
```

I really need both `grequests` and `boto3` in my code. but I cannot import `grequests` if I want to use boto3 for s3 .
Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a known issue: https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests/issues/123.

Solutions suggested in the Github thread include changing order of imports and using an alternative library like https://pypi.org/project/fgrequests/.